# Why Float error is different in C?

Tags: objective-c, c, floating-point, precision

Please see the pictures:

[image][image]

I'm amazing the result is different.

Comment: Floats only have about 7 decimal digits of precision. You are computing `price2` by dividing two floats. (What you do with a result doesn't change how that result is computed. That you're storing it in a `CGFloat` does not cause the division to keep that much precision.)

Comment: Is it really too hard to show pure text as text instead of a picture?

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Not a duplicate of that one.

Answer (score 6):

A `CGFloat` is actually a `double` on 64 bit platforms. (It was a `float` on old 32 bit platforms.)

So here you're dividing a `double` by a `double`:

```
CGFloat price    =    88888736      /     a;
        ^^^^^         ^^^^^^^^            ^
       double        int -> double      double
```

and here you're dividing a `double` by a `float`:

```
CGFloat price2    =   88888736     /   100.0f;
        ^^^^^^        ^^^^^^^^         ^^^^^^
        double       int -> double      float
```

Change `100.0f` to either `100.0` or `(CGFloat)100` and you should be fine.

<kbd>[LIVE DEMO](https://ideone.com/trA2yq)</kbd>

Comment: Maybe the non-obvious part is that the first division is a `double` division because it divides an integer literal and a `double`  and the second is `float` division because it divides integer literal and `float` literal.

Comment: @Sulthan: thanks - I've added a more detailed explanation now.

Comment: You have not answered a question since last November. What happened? It seems SO has slowed.

Comment: @Zboson: heh - very observant - it's just a combination of factors really: been super-busy with work and domestic stuff + more SIMD experts around these days (Peter Cordes is quite prolific !) + majority of new questions seem to be either low quality or duplicates. Still here though... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

`CGFloat` is a `double` on your machine, therefore what you are doing is this:

```
double a = 100.00f
double price = 88888736 / a

float a2 = 100.00f // `float` type enforced by the trailing `f`
double price2 = 88888736 / a2
```

The difference is that in the first case the division is a `double` division while in the second case this is a `float` division where the result is *then* assigned to a `double`. Since `float` division has less precision, you get the result you are seeing.